# Dynamically added wizard steps are not visible after postback

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to add wizard steps dynamically to the wizard control in asp.net. Here first i have deleted default wizard steps and then i tried to add two wizard steps dynamically.then nothing is visible on the screen. If i keep the default wizard steps(step1 & step2) and i added two steps dynamically , in this case it is adding properly, but when i click on any one of the step,dynamically added steps becomes invisible.....
why, please give some guidance regarding this...........

thanks

Answer (score 2):

All controls that added dynamically must be added everytime postback occured not later then Page_Load event handler.

[Why do dynamic controls disappear on postback](http://forums.asp.net/t/1186195.aspx/1)
[Dynamic Web Controls, Postbacks, and View State](https://web.archive.org/web/20210330142645/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/092904-1.aspx)